Problem consuming ASP.NET Core Web API in ASP.NET Core MVC web app
I am getting an error message of

STATUS code 404 method not found

when reading an API from an ASP.NET Core MVC web app.
Here is my API code:
[HttpGet("ParticipantID")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Participant>> GetParticipantsByParticipantID(long ParticipantID)
{
    var participant_id = await context.Participants.FindAsync(ParticipantID);

    if (participant_id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(participant_id);
}

The call to the API is here:
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(long ParticipantID)
{
    url = configuration.GetValue<string>("apiurl:baseurl");
    url = url + "participant/";

    Participants participant = new Participants();

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url + ParticipantID).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Participants>(result);

        if (data != null)
        {
            participant = data;
        }
    }

    return View();
}

I am a new to ASP.NET Core - I will be thankful if someone can help me with this.
Here is my appsettings.json file
"apiurl": {
    "baseurl": "https://localhost:7194/"
}


Currently, the route for the GetParticipantsByParticipantID method is "api/<Controller>/ParticipantID" but not "api/<Controller>/<ParticipantID value>".
Change your route as below as route parameter:
[HttpGet("{ParticipantID}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Participant>> GetParticipantsByParticipantID(long ParticipantID)

Reference: Attribute routing with Http verb attributes
You are missing the "/api" prefix in url.
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Edit(long ParticipantID)
{
    url = configuration.GetValue<string>("apiurl:baseurl");
    url = url + "/api/participant/";

    ....
}


I used the same as prescribed but found this error message

Can you share the error message?

I used the same as prescribed but found this error message
{StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:{  Date: Wed, 01 May 2024 13:10:18 GMT  Server: Kestrel  Transfer-Encoding: chunked  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8}}

Okay, does your Web API include Swagger API (middleware)? If yes, you can view the generated API documentation to find whether what is the route path for your GetParticipantsByParticipantID API.

Please find it here, by the way its working fine on swagger
[link]https://ibb.co/TKdBZfC

Updated my answer. You are missing "/api" in the URL.
